# Show the Equivalence of Difference Predicate versions of induction

Tags: logic

I have come cross several different predicate definition of induction

$$(P(0) \land \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, P(n) \implies P(n+1) ) \implies \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, P(n) $$

$$(\exists n \in \mathbb{N},P(n)) \implies (P(0) \lor \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \neg P(n) \land P(n+1))$$

$$(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, P(n) \implies P(n+1)) \implies (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, P(0) \implies P(n))$$

$$(\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \neg P(0) \land P(n)) \implies \exists n\in \mathbb{N}, \neg P(n) \land P(n+1)$$

The first one is the mot common one; however, I don't see why they are all equivalent; some of them are even quit bit counter intuitive as definition for induction.

Can someone show how to prove they are equivalent use basic logic axiom and rule?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @DanielV; No, I was reading the logic book, and the author states that they are equivalent and the proof left to readers;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(3) and (1) are the same because:

$$(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, P(n) \implies P(n+1)) \implies (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \underbrace{ P(0)}_A \implies \underbrace{P(n)}_B)$$

Apply $\forall x~A \to B$ is equivalent to $A \to \forall x~B$ when $x$ isn't in A$:

$$\underbrace{(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, P(n) \implies P(n+1))}_A \implies (\underbrace{P(0)}_B \implies \underbrace{\forall n \in \mathbb{N},~P(n)}_C)$$

Now apply $A \to (B \to C)$ is equivalent to $(B \land A) \to C$

$$\underbrace{(P(0) \land \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, P(n) \implies P(n+1) )}_A \implies \underbrace{\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, P(n)}_B$$

And you are at 1.  Now apply contrapositive $A \to B$ is equivalent to $\lnot B \to \lnot A$:

$$\lnot \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, P(n) \implies \lnot (P(0) \land \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, P(n) \implies P(n+1) )$$

And Demorgan's:

$$\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \lnot P(n) \implies (\lnot P(0) \lor \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \lnot \lnot P(n) \land \lnot P(n+1) )$$

Let $Q(n) = \lnot P(n)$:

$$\underbrace{\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, Q(n)}_A \implies (\underbrace{Q(0)}_B \lor \underbrace{\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \lnot Q(n) \land Q(n+1)}_C )$$

And you've got rule 2.  Now $A \to (B \lor C)$ is equivalent to $(\lnot B \land A) \to C$:

$$(\underbrace{\lnot Q(0)}_A \land \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \underbrace{Q(n)}_B) \implies \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \lnot Q(n) \land Q(n+1)$$

And applying $A \land \exists x,~B$ is equivalent to $\exists x,~A \land B$, you get rule (4):

$$(\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \neg Q(0) \land Q(n)) \implies \exists n\in \mathbb{N}, \neg Q(n) \land Q(n+1)$$

All equivalent in classical first order logic.